# Mutable Data in OCaml

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml, mutable

I've created a mutable data structure in OCaml, however when I go to access it, it gives a weird error,

Here is my code

```
type vector = {a:float;b:float};;
type vec_store = {mutable seq:vector array;mutable size:int};;

let max_seq_length = ref 200;;

exception Out_of_bounds;;
exception Vec_store_full;;

let vec_mag {a=c;b=d} = sqrt( c**2.0 +. d**2.0);;


let make_vec_store() = 
    let vecarr = ref ((Array.create (!max_seq_length)) {a=0.0;b=0.0}) in
         {seq= !vecarr;size=0};;
```

When I do this in ocaml top-level

```
let x = make _ vec _store;;
```

and then try to do `x.size` I get this error

```
Error: This expression has type unit -> vec_store
       but an expression was expected of type vec_store
```

Whats seems to be the problem? I cant see why this would not work.

Thanks,
Faisal

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`make_vec_store` is a function. When you say `let x = make_vec_store`, you are setting x to be that function, just like if you'd written `let x = 1`, that would make x the number 1. What you *want* is the result of calling that function. According to `make_vec_store`'s definition, it takes `()` (also known as "unit") as an argument, so you would write `let x = make_vec_store ()`.

Comment: ahh Very very good explanation! I knew something was going wrong, as this code had worked earlier. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 4):

try x = make_ vec_store()

Answer (score 2):

As a follow up to the excellent answere provided.  You can tell that your example line:

```
# let x = make_vec_store;;
val x : unit -> vec_store = <fun>
```

returns a function as the repl will tell you this.  You can see from the output that x is of type `<fun>` that takes no parameters `unit` and returns a type `vec_store`.

Contrast this to the declaration

```
# let x = 1;;
val x : int = 1
```

which tells you that x is of type int and value 1.